# Animation Duration should be relative to height and width

Tags: html, css

I have a div whose height and width will be dynamic. I'm tring to have an dotted animation border to that div. Problem which i'm facing is animation duration is not relative to the height and width. i.e whatever height and width its animation should be at same speed across all the corners

```css
  .dynamic {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden
  }
  .dynamic::before {
    animation: slideDash 2.5s infinite linear;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    outline: 1px dashed #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(23, 163, 102);
    width: 200%;
  }
  .dynamic::after {
    animation: slideDash 2.5s infinite linear reverse;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    outline: 1px dashed #fff;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(23, 163, 102);
    width: 200%;
  }
  .dynamic div::before {
    animation: slideDashRev 2.5s infinite linear reverse;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    outline: 1px dashed #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(23, 163, 102);
    height: 200%;
  }
  .dynamic div::after {
    animation: slideDashRev 2.5s infinite linear;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    outline: 1px dashed #fff;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(23, 163, 102);
    height: 200%;
  }
  @keyframes slideDash {
    from {
      transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    to {
      transform: translateX(0%);
    }
  }
  @keyframes slideDashRev {
    from {
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    to {
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="dynamic">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing the height and width of the parent. u can see that animation speed varies. I understand its bcoz of the even duration. But is there is anyway to overcome this

Comment: Umm, can JS be involved? If the width and height is not equal, they should not have equal animation duration.

Answer (score 1):

Just correcting the direction of the animation

```css
.dynamic {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: red;
}
.dynamic .line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.dynamic .line:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.dynamic .line:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-left: -164px; /* margin-left=(minus)((height+width)/2)-(border-width) */
}
.dynamic .line:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.dynamic .line:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-left: 164px; /* margin-left=((height+width)/2)-(border-width) */
}
.dynamic .line:nth-of-type(1) i, .dynamic .line:nth-of-type(3) i {
  -webkit-animation: move 2.5s infinite linear reverse;
  animation: move 2.5s infinite linear reverse;
}
.dynamic .line:nth-of-type(2) i, .dynamic .line:nth-of-type(4) i {
  -webkit-animation: move 2.5s infinite linear;
  animation: move 2.5s infinite linear;
}
.dynamic .line i {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
}
.dynamic .text {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dynamic">
    <div class="line"><i></i>
    </div>
    <div class="line"><i></i>
    </div>
    <div class="line"><i></i>
    </div>
    <div class="line"><i></i>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Same Direction!!</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet.

```css
.dynamic {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: green;
}
.dynamic .line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.dynamic .line:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.dynamic .line:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-left: -164px;
  /* margin-left=(minus)((height+width)/2)-(border-width) */
}
.dynamic .line:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.dynamic .line:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  margin-left: 164px;
  /* margin-left=((height+width)/2)-(border-width) */
}
.dynamic .line i {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  -webkit-animation: move 2.5s infinite linear reverse;
  animation: move 2.5s infinite linear reverse;
}
.dynamic .text {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dynamic">
    <div class="line"><i></i>
    </div>
    <div class="line"><i></i>
    </div>
    <div class="line"><i></i>
    </div>
    <div class="line"><i></i>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Some text here</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: http://www.cssscript.com/demo/neon-style-rotating-borders-with-pure-css-css3/
 Already refered this link. This doesnt suits me since i have dynamic width and height

Answer (score 0):

```
.dynamic {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width:  50px;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Having the same dimensions for the `height` and and `width` makes the animation speed the same.

Note: You can replace the `50` with any dimension of your choice.

Comment: in my case it varies